# Group by one column and iterate the ranking from 1 to 5 for whole file

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

Total recs: 50 records

Rec id is the unique id in the file.

Input file will be as follows:

```
rec id1
rec id1
rec id1
rec id2
rec id3
rec id3
rec id4
rec id6
rec id6
rec id7
rec id7

Output file should have 
   A      RANKS
rec id1   1
rec id1   1
rec id1   1
rec id2   2
rec id3   3
rec id3   3
rec id4   4
rec id6   5
rec id6   5
rec id7   1
rec id7   1
rec id8   2
rec id8   2
```

and so ...on

Once rank reaches 5 it should start again from 1 for next group by A column

What i did for now

step 1: group by rec id's
step 2: I did For loop and got the output..but its not fast in python..
is there anyway to make it fast by using apply function etc..or some other existing function

Code i used:

```
curr_rec_id = df.ix[i,'rec_id']
for i in xrange(len(df.index)):
    if df.ix[i,'rec id'] == curr_rec_id:
        df.ix[i,'rank'] = j
        df.to_csv('c:\out.csv')
    else:
         curr_rec_id = df.ix[i,'rec id']
         j=j+1
    df.ix[i,'rank'] = j
    df.to_csv('c:out.csv')  
    if j==5:
        j=1
```

This takes long time if recs are many in the input file.

Is there any efficient way and fastest way of doing it..for eg: using apply function or group by function etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) and divide by `modulo` `%` with `5`. Last you need add `1`:

```
print df
          A
0   rec id1
1   rec id1
2   rec id1
3   rec id2
4   rec id3
5   rec id3
6   rec id4
7   rec id6
8   rec id6
9   rec id7
10  rec id7
11  rec id8
12  rec id8

df['RANKS'] = ( pd.factorize(df['A'])[0] % 5 ) + 1
print df
          A  RANKS
0   rec id1      1
1   rec id1      1
2   rec id1      1
3   rec id2      2
4   rec id3      3
5   rec id3      3
6   rec id4      4
7   rec id6      5
8   rec id6      5
9   rec id7      1
10  rec id7      1
11  rec id8      2
12  rec id8      2
```

Or you can use [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html), but first you need substract `1` for counting `modulo` `%`:

```
df['RANKS'] = (( df['A'].rank(method='dense') - 1 ) % 5 ) + 1
```

Comment: Thanks so much..Brilliant answer.